# How to disable the Hamburger Menu for certain views in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a login page that I want to show upon App launch within my Main Window that has a Hamburger Menu in the left side. How can I hide/disable this?

This is a desktop application created by using WPF along with MahApps.Metro library.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Window size, either a larger menu should be shown on top, or the Hamburger button with the menus in the SplitView pane. This functionality is offered by the adaptive trigger. The following code snippet changes the visibility of the horizontal menu and the Hamburger button depending on Window sizes 320 and 720.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="MediumState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="HorizontalMenu.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Setter Target="HamburgerButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />               
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="XSmallState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
               <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="320" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="HamburgerButton.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Typical triggers for the Window sizes are 320, 548, 720, and 1024.

The menu for the larger Window is just defined within a StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" x:Name="HorizontalMenu" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Button Content="One" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Content="Two" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```